# INA219- I2c bus weird behavior

Tags: i2c, pcb-assembly, texas-instruments, ina219

I have a PCB assembly where I built the circuit in the schematic below. I did not start programming yet.

[image]

I'm getting the weirdest problem. When I check the voltages in the SDA and SCL lines (which should be 5 V because of the pull-up resistors) I get values close to 0.7 V. I try de-soldering the isolator and check the voltages again, with only the INA219 circuit assembled and I got another weird result the SCL line has a value of 4.8 V and the SDA line gets a result close to 0.7 V.

Can anyone help me debug this circuit?

Comment: No faults in the schematic, but check voltages on every pin and suspect wiring connection faults or IC damage

Comment: Is the MCU side pulled up with resistors? What value? To which voltage? Is it a 5V MCU?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 i doubt it will be a damaged IC i build the same circuit in another board and got the same results

Comment: @Justme The MCU side is pulled up to  5 V with 4.7k resistors, and i m suplling the mcu (avr128da32 ) with  5 V

Comment: Given the non-inverting simple transfer function, Test all voltages and impedances with a load. Then CM noise can be shunted with an RF cap. for testing purposes.  I suspect that noise will be large between grounds